# How to set the a nav links bottom the a nav brand

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to ask you how can I set the a nav links bottom the a nav brand in the center. I've literally done no code, I'm just getting started but I can show you a page link that I want to do like:
https://aforkandapencil.com/
so the a nav brand is the "a fork and a pencil"
and the a nav links are "recipes" and "newsletter"
I'm doing this with Bootstrap

Comment: Can you share with us, what you have done so far ? Or give us an example of your try

Comment: I told you that I've not done anything yet just want to know how to do that on a navbar

Comment: Ok, start coding and come back with your try

Comment: Im waiting for someone to show me how to do this so then I can start coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Flexbox with bootstrap. Checkout this Codepen here created for your problem: https://codepen.io/pro_animator/pen/XWNKNGm

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="logo-container d-flex justify-content-center">
        <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/5ae2b8fdf93fd4d57303a71d/1609410815009-NBBBB2KLYPZ597UKWFWE/logo-005CA5.png?content-type=image%2Fpng"/>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
        <div class="p-2"><a href="#">Recipes</a></div>
        <div class="p-2"><a href="#">Newsletter</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.logo-container img {
    height: 40px;
    width: auto;
}
```

PS: Edited my answer.

Comment: @Leart edited the answer. check now